# how to use replaceWith() jquery function with toggle

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Actually i am using bootstrap with jquery just to toggle the content of a div. but i just face certain problems while exchanging the content.
I just want to use replaceWith() to toggle the content of a div on a button click.

```
     function replace(){
      $('#side').toggleClass('col-sm-2').toggleClass('col-sm-1');
      $('#rest').toggleClass('col-sm-10').toggleClass('col-sm-11');
         $( ".first" ).replaceWith( $( ".second" ) );
      }
```

Comment: can you share the relevant html

Comment: your code seems correct and please provide your html or fiddle to sort it out.

Comment: instead of replaceWith, have you tried with show / hide?

Comment: What problems are you facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should use show and hide method of jquery instead of replacewith. there are certain limitations with each function of jquery.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery's replaceWith() assumes you wish to remove the target element from the DOM and replace it with the element you specify.

In contrast, from what you describe, you wish to replace the "content" of one element with either another element or it's content.  In either case, I would suggest one of the following:

```
$('#targetElement').html( $( "#contentElement" ) );  //Replaces the content of of the target with the intended element.
$('#targetElement').html( $( "#contentElement" ).html() );  //Replaces the content of of the target with the content of the intended element.
```

I hope this helps!  Good luck.